# How can I generate serial numbers in SQL(ORACLE) using MAX+1?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I know how to create and use sequence but I'm not able to find any queries related to 'max+1' condition on web.

Comment: Don't create keys using `max() + 1`. Your implementation will either not scale well for multiple users (=will be terribly slow) or will simply return wrong values. Why don't you want to use a sequence?

Comment: Okay, thanx for the suggestion, I had no idea that the performance could get slow if I use 'max+1' approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want but based on your question i guess you want to know how to increment the sequence.

If that's the case you have to use sequence_name.nextval.

Comment: I am using sequence but to learn about new thing I decided to ask this question.
Thanks for your answer. :)